# no new content displayed at web application after submitting form using GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a web application running on GAE for Java and using the app engine Datastore and Objectify 4.

When a user submit a form with several fields from the web, the application's logic is supposed to post these values into the datastore, reading a list of data (included these last values) and return to the web showing these last changes submitted along with the rest of data. Most of the times it works fine.

However, sometimes (it really happens very few times), **the new values are saved but when returning to the web, they don't appear on the web**. But just **refreshing the explorer (so refreshing the process of reading) some seconds later the values are there**, as they should be from the first time.

Testing in my local environment, this has happened to me some few times as well, and I got an error saying something like the **text file used for simulating the datastore (called local_db.bin) was not close properly** during the "saving" or "reading" process, probably because the process was too quick, and the new values were not available yet (that's my opinion though). So I guess something similar could happen on the real Datastore.

Do you know how to avoid this issue in a simple way? (If possible, avoiding synchronization blocks and so on)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're running into issues with [eventual consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency), as a result of using the high replication datastore without ancestor queries. From [Structuring Data for Strong Consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) (emphasis added):

> Google App Engine's High Replication Datastore (HRD) provides high
>   availability for your reads and writes by storing data synchronously
>   in multiple data centers. However, the delay from the time a write is
>   committed until it becomes visible in all data centers means that
>   queries across multiple entity groups (non-ancestor queries) can only
>   guarantee eventually consistent results. Consequently, **the results of
>   such queries may sometimes fail to reflect recent changes to the
>   underlying data**.
>
> **To obtain strongly consistent query results, you need to use an
>   ancestor query limiting the results to a single entity group.** This
>   works because entity groups are a unit of consistency as well as
>   transactionality. All data operations are applied to the entire group;
>   an ancestor query won't return its results until the entire entity
>   group is up to date. If your application relies on strongly consistent
>   results for certain queries, you may need to take this into
>   consideration when designing your data model. This page discusses best
>   practices for structuring your data to support strong consistency.

Here's an example of using an ancestor query from that document for writing:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;

String guestbookName = req.getParameter("guestbookName");
Key guestbookKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Guestbook", guestbookName);
String content = req.getParameter("content");
Date date = new Date();

// Place greeting in same entity group as guestbook
Entity greeting = new Entity("Greeting", guestbookKey);
greeting.setProperty("user", user);
greeting.setProperty("date", date);
greeting.setProperty("content", content);
```

And reading:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;

DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Key guestbookKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Guestbook", guestbookName);
Query query = new Query("Greeting", guestbookKey)
                    .setAncestor(guestbookKey)
                    .addSort("date", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);

List<Entity> greetings = datastore.prepare(query)
                                  .asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(10));
```

Caveats to using ancestor queries are discussed in more detail in the document.

Comment: Thanks for answering and putting me on the right track. I forgot to mention I was working with Objectify 4, and looking its documentation it also goes through the eventual consistency issue you point. In my case I can fix my issue with [Transaction Inheritance](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Transactions).